# Case conversion of large dictionary word set

Tags: haskell, optimization, data-structures

I'm trying to match words from a dictionary, case-insensitively. My initial approach
looks like so:

1. read dict; convert all words to lowercase, store in set.
2. check new word for membership in set

Is there a better (more efficient) way to achieve this? I'm new to Haskell.

```
import System.IO
import Data.Text (toLower, pack, unpack)
import Data.Set (fromList, member)

main = do
  let path = "/usr/share/dict/american-english"
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  hSetEncoding h utf8
  contents <- hGetContents h
  let mySet = (fromList . map (unpack . toLower . pack) . lines) contents
  putStrLn $ show $ member "acadia" mySet
```

Comment: The approach looks fine to me. Maybe for strings there's some optimized trie package somewhere on hackage, but this is already good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just work with `Text` directly instead of converting to/from Strings.

`Data.Text.IO` contains versions of `hGetContents`, `readFile`, etc. for reading Text from files, and `Data.Text` has `lines` for Text.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import System.IO
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Set as S

main = do
  let path = "/usr/share/dict/american-english"
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  hSetEncoding h utf8
  contents <- T.hGetContents h
  let mySet = (S.fromList . map T.toLower . T.lines) contents
  putStrLn $ show $ S.member "acadia" mySet
```

By using `T.tolower` and `T.lines` we avoid explicit pack/unpack calls.

`mySet` is now a set of Text values rather than of Strings. By using
the OverloadedStrings pragma the literal `"acadia"` will be interpreted
as a Text value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you propose is reasonable. Some few remarks, mostly unrelated to the main question:

1. It would be more efficient to restrict your self to using only `Text` and not `String`.
2. Prefer the `toCaseFold` function to `toLower`, it's more appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you found my first answer helpful, let me propose another approach...

A boggle solver I wrote simply reads in the entire dictionary as a single ByteString, and to look up words performs a binary search on that ByteString.

The dictionary must already be in sorted order and normalized to lower case, but usually this is not a problem since the dictionary is static
and known in advance.

Of course, when you compute `(lo+hi)/2` in performing the binary search you might land in the middle of word, so you simply back up to the beginning of the current word.

The main advantage of this is that loading the dictionary is extremely fast and it is memory efficient. Moreover, the search algorithm has good memory locality. I haven't measured it, but I wouldn't be surprised if creating a `Data.Set` will more than double the size of the raw data.

The code is available here: https://github.com/erantapaa/hoggle